# font in bootstrap select box

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I try to display select option text with a Poppins font. The class is

```
.poppinsregular14diese00000061 {
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #00000061;
}
```

The fiddle is the following : https://jsfiddle.net/flamant/dvzh57wu/14/

But the displayed text is not showing the same as the same type of class text within a div or a text input

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like .custom-select-lg class overrides your font-size (1,25rem), than on the hierarchy, .custom-select will override your font-size to 1rem. If you really want that 14px to apply to the options, than use inline style

```
<select  class="browser-default custom-select custom-select-lg mb-3" style="float:left;width: 255px;height: 40px; font-size:14px"  placeholder="By myself" formControlName="byWho">
```

On the other hand, I don't really advise inline styling as you did, code becomes messy after a while